# Is there a way to pass reference into a method without 'ref' keyword c Sharp

Tags: c#

So I want to be able to set all the variable to false except the Boolean referenced, but this variable varies  so i cannot use the required 'ref' keyword. Is there a way in which the keyword is not needed or a better way of doing this

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(this)
        {
            SetStatus(Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i], i);
        }
        if(this)
        {
            SetStatus(Program.runningHamiltons[i], i);
        }
    }
}

public static void SetStatus(ref bool status, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SetStatus");
    Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.runningHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.userAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.methodEndHamiltons[i] = false;
    status = true;
}
```

Hope this makes sense, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is. Create a class with field you want to be referenced and there you are. Use it in method.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in **c#** are [`Reference type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and you can create an class like this

```cs
public class CheckStatus
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

then pass the an instance of class to method like this

```cs
public static void SetStatus(CheckStatus status,int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SetStatus");
    Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.runningHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.userAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.methodEndHamiltons[i] = false;
    status.Status = true;
}
```

and

```cs
public static void ReadFile()
{
    CheckStatus status = new CheckStatus();
    if(this)
    {
        status.Status = Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i];
        SetStatus(status, i);
        Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i] = status.Status;
    }
    if(this)
    {
        status.Status = Program.runningHamiltons[i];
        SetStatus(status, i);
        Program.runningHamiltons[i] = status.Status;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will **not** set `Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i]` to `true` in the first `if`, or `Program.runningHamiltons[i]` to `true` in the second `if`

Comment: Well, seeing your updated code, OP could just as well get rid of the entire `CheckStatus` part, having a `SetStatus(int i)` and then replace both `= status.Status` with `= true`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass the list itself as such: (assuming they are `List<bool>` but if not, just replace that with actual collection type)

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    if(/* condition 1 */)
    {
        SetStatus(Program.systemAbortedHamiltons, i);
    }
    if(/* condition 2 */)
    {
        SetStatus(Program.runningHamiltons, i);
    }
}

public static void SetStatus(List<bool> statuses, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SetStatus");
    Program.systemAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.runningHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.userAbortedHamiltons[i] = false;
    Program.methodEndHamiltons[i] = false;
    statuses[i] = true;
}
```

Below is a quick test to see if it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<bool> myList = new List<bool>
        {
            true, true, true
        };

        // Outputs "True"
        Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);

        SetFalse(myList, 0);

        // Outputs "False"
        Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);
    }

    static void SetFalse(List<bool> l, int i)
    {
        l[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> `True`
>   `False`